# C# MVC Resourcefile get string from variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources

This is how I get a resource string in one of my views:

```
@MyProject.Resources.ResourceEN.MyResourceStringName
//Gives back mystring in desired language
```

**What if I had a string variable that I wanted to send in?**

```
@string HelloWorld;
@MyProject.Resources.ResourceEN.HelloWorld
```

This won't work obviously because it looks for the resource name "HelloWorld" and not the content of that string variable.

**Is it somehow possible to use a variable for this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ResourceManager's GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk(v=vs.110).aspx) method to return the value of the specified string resource using the variable:

```
@string HelloWorld;
@(new ResourceManager(typeof(MyProject.Resources.ResourceEN)).GetString(HelloWorld))
```

Or better yet consider adding a helper method/extension-method on `HtmlHelper`, something like:

```
public static string MyResource<T>(this HtmlHelper html, object key) {
    return new ResourceManager(typeof(T)).GetString(key.ToString());
}
```

which can then be used as follows:

```
@string HelloWorld;
@(Html.MyResource<MyProject.Resources.ResourceEN>(HelloWorld))
```

** **EDIT** **

Bear in mind that the MVC Razor parser sees `<` and thinks it's an HTML tag thus you need to wrap the call in parentheses to force it to treat the entire call as a single expression as above.

Comment: How do you use the extension method in your view?

@Html.GetString<resourcesv>("test") doesn't work because razor stops working within <> tag.

@{Html.GetString<ResourceSV>(item.Name);} Works but it doesn't display the result in the view..

Comment: Try `@(Html.GetString<ResourceSV>(item.Name))`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value to a variable like this:

```
@{ string HelloWorld = MyProject.Resources.ResourceEN.HelloWorld }
```

On a side note, it is unusual to specifically call out `ResourceEN` in your code. The culture is normally specified by setting the `CurrentUICulture` to the current thread and the call to `MyProject.Resources` will automatically select the correct language file based on the culture.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

It defaults to the culture that is set in the web.config file if not set explicitly within the current request.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
</system.web>
```